# MongoDB admin commands with mgo driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

Is it possible, given admin creds, to run mongo shell commands such as `db.stats()`, `rs.status()` and `db.serverStatus()` external to the mongo shell via the official Go driver for MongoDB (mgo)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is certainly possible, but first you need to bear in mind that the "commands" you have listed are actually shell helpers.  You will need to get the real commands that they represent to run them via `mgo` [Session.Run](https://github.com/go-mgo/mgo/blob/v2/session.go#L1771).

There are a couple of ways to do that, the first is to just run `db.listCommands()` in the shell and find the appropriate one.  The second way to do this is to run the helper you wish to emulate without parentheses.  For example:

```
> rs.status
function () { return db._adminCommand("replSetGetStatus"); }
```

As you can see, what the helper actually does is run the `replSetGetStatus` command against the `admin` database.  Similarly you will find that `db.stats()` actually runs the `dbstats` command.  The `db.serverStatus()` helper is the only one of the three you listed that you can pretty much run as-is.

Here's a very simple example of running all three - I show two forms of the call, one that just passes a string and the more general option that passes in the full command document - I ran this on a test `mongod` without auth, so you would have to add that piece yourself to test on an auth-enabled instance:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    // Optional. Switch the session to a monotonic behavior.
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
    result := bson.M{}
    if err := session.DB("admin").Run(bson.D{{"serverStatus", 1}}, &result); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
    if err := session.DB("test").Run("dbstats", &result); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
    if err := session.DB("admin").Run("replSetGetStatus", &result); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: Dude @Adam, you are awesome. This is exactly what I was asking and more. Thanks you!

Comment: Thanks @adam. Completely answered my question :)

Comment: The *else*s are redundant.

Answer (score -3):

[get stats](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#GetStats)

[manually running server status commands](https://github.com/deftlabs/presentations/blob/master/golang-ny-meetup-mar-12-2013/src/meetup/hello_mgo.go#L32)

Comment: answers with just links typically are not good answers.. you should pull the data necessary to answer the question, then source the material.